# scroll bar in Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I have a little problem with the scrollbar on my autocomplete list.
Enter the letter "o" in the search bar and see what happens.
Yet I added line 139 in the CSS but no scrollbar :

```
overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; padding-right: 20px
```

However I put:

```
  <body style="overflow:hidden;">
```

in html because I want a fullscreen display.

http://jsfiddle.net/fAe78/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    right: 0 !important;
    left: auto !important;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/fAe78/1/

Comment: I replaced //   right: 0 !important;
    left: auto !important;//
by:

    // margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;//

And works very well.
thank you